# Right-centered columns in tabular*

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I'd like to right-center a column within a `tabular*` environment. See the following snippet:

```
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} llc}
\hline 
\textbf{Art} & \textbf{Stundensatz} & \textbf{Gesamt} \\ 
\hline 
Doing this & 1,5 à 100 Euro & 150,00 Euro \\ 
\hline 
This \& That & 3 à 100 Euro & 300,00 Euro \\
\hline
Even more stuff and corrections & 3,5 à 100 Euro & 350,00 Euro \\ 
\hline
Hearing & 1 à 100 Euro & 100,00 Euro \\
\hline
MwSt. in Höhe von 19\% &  & 171,00 Euro \\
\hline
Gesamt & & 1071,00 Euro \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular*}
```

Which looks like

[image]

How to have the last two columns right-centered?

Comment: To right align the last two columns, use  `\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} rr}` instead of `\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} llc}` By the way, you defined 4 columns but only use 3 of them

Comment: What do you mean by `right-centered`?

Comment: @Bernard: Maybe not well phrased, but I meant what leandriis answered.

Comment: @Jan: The correct english term for 'rechtsbündig'  would be `flush right`, `right-aligned` or `right-justified`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to right align the second and third column, use `r` instead of `l`. In the following MWE, I have also removed the fourth column cpacifier (`c`)  as you only need three columns. I have also added  `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` in order to center the column headers of the second and third column.

The second table in the MWE ise done using `tabularx` to make sure that long entries in the first column are automatically split into two or more lines so that the table's with does not exceed the textwidth. In this second table, I have also used rules from the `booktabs` package. These lines have some vertical white space above and below them.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}


\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} rr}
\hline 
\textbf{Art} & \textbf{Stundensatz} & \textbf{Gesamt} \\ 
\hline 
Doing this & 1,5 à 100 Euro & 150,00 Euro \\ 
\hline 
This \& That & 3 à 100 Euro & 300,00 Euro \\
\hline
Even more stuff and corrections & 3,5 à 100 Euro & 350,00 Euro \\ 
\hline
Hearing & 1 à 100 Euro & 100,00 Euro \\
\hline
MwSt. in Höhe von 19\% &  & 171,00 Euro \\
\hline
Gesamt & & 1071,00 Euro \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular*} 

\bigskip

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xrr}
\toprule 
\textbf{Art} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Stundensatz}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Gesamt}} \\ 
\midrule 
Doing this & 1,5 à 100 Euro & 150,00 Euro \\  
This \& That & 3 à 100 Euro & 300,00 Euro \\
Even more stuff and corrections & 3,5 à 100 Euro & 350,00 Euro \\ 
Hearing & 1 à 100 Euro & 100,00 Euro \\
MwSt. in Höhe von 19\% &  & 171,00 Euro \\
a very long entry a very long entry a very long entry a very long entry   &  &  \\
\midrule
Gesamt &  & 1071,00 Euro \\ 
\bottomrule 
\end{tabularx} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, very appreciated.